# Calling a SQL Server user-def function in an MS Access query, getting "Undefined Function dbo.Funcname in expression"

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

In MS Access (I think it's version 365 as that's what a Help subject references, but there's no "help/about" option), I'm modifying a query due to a change in business logic. The query references tables on a SQL Server (2016) server via an ODBC connection.

In "SQL View" of the query, I added a clause to the "WHERE" section:

AND (dbo_GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate( dbo_Name.ID, Date() = 'FM') )

It saves it ok (which Access doesn't do when there's a syntax error.)

Running the query, a message dialog pops up: 
Undefined function 'dbo_GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate' in expression.

I've also tried it in the SQL View with "dbo." and no prefix before "Get), instead of "dbo_"

The function works fine when run in SQL Server.
The Access query works fine when I remove that AND clause from SQL view.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a function defined in SQL server from Access, you need to set your query to be a passthrough query. This is done in design view using the *Passthrough query* button. The name of the function uses the dot, `dbo.GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate`

Also, if you want to use SQL server functions, you can't mix them with Access functions. This means `Date()` should become `GETDATE()`.

Else, you'd have to implement your business logic in VBA to run it locally. But usually, implementing it in T-SQL and running it on SQL Server is faster.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what/where the function dbo_GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate()  resides.

Anything that runs 100% sql server side (such as a view) will require you to convert the VBA function to what we call a "scaler" function in T-SQL. You can thus re-write the above VBA function in T-SQL function. Once you create this function, then JUST LIKE in Access SQL how you  can use use a custom VBA function in any sql, you can do the same in T-SQL.

In most cases that custom VBA function you used in Access SQL is likely a rather short function, so converting such functions to T-sql functions (they are called scaler functions) will result in the same development process.

About the only downside is while you can use the exact same function name in t-sql, unforntatly all scaler functions require the schemea prefix (I REALLY wish this was not the case). So if you are cutting and pasting client side Access SQL into SSMS and creating a view? Well, you have to add a dbo. in front of the function name. But, all in all, re-creating the VBA function as T-SQL is a great idea for such migration projects. I had a custom GST() function in VBA. And to move the sql and parts to SQL, then I re-created the GST() function in T-SQL and thus I was able to continue to use the GST() functon in my t-sql queries and views.

Last but not least?

Well, in the access client side, you will no doubt be linked to the view. So, create a client side query on the linked view, and you can THEN include your custom VBA function.

If you really need and want to use a linked view, and not a client query based on a linked view, then you can simply re-create the custom VBA function as a t-sql scaler function, and then continue to use that function in any t-sql query, including views.

So a client query on the linked view can include + use your function. However, for ease of use, and best performance, then consider creating that VBA function routine as a t-sql routine. While t-sql is somewhat limited compared to VBA, it has loops, string expressions, query ability, and really quite much the same set of features that you would find in a typical VBA routine - especially ones being used as part of the sql query as an expression.

## Edit

You have this:

```
AND (dbo_GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate( dbo_Name.ID, Date() = 'FM') )
```

That don't look right. It is assumed that this Function returns some string, and you have:

```
dbo_GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate( dbo_Name.ID, Date()
```

It should be:

```
dbo_GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate( dbo_Name.ID, Date() )
```

Don't really care where, when or what you do with this function, but you need a closing bracket for the function. As I stated, you also have to prefix ANY scaler function with the schema. So thus we get:

```
dbo.dbo_GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate( dbo_Name.ID, Date() )
```

HOWEVER, there is no date() function in SQL server. You have to use GETDATE()

HOWEVER HOWEVER!! GETDATE() will return today and ALSO the time portion.

So, if you only want today, and only a date, and not a date time?

Then you have to use this:

```
 CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

So now we have this legal expression:

```
dbo.dbo_GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate( dbo_Name.ID, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) )
```

And then with above, that function is assumed to return a varChar, so we can now swap the above into your where clause and we get:

```
AND 
(
dbo.dbo_GetPrevNameCatAsOfDate( dbo_Name.ID, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) ) = 'FM'
)
```

So there is no DATE() t-sql. And you have to prefix with dbo.

Comment: Hi Albert,The function resides in the SQL Server, same database as the linked-to tables I'm selecting from. This is not VBA code in the Access app, it's just right-clicking on a query, Design View, SQL View. There is no SQL view.  Thanks...

Comment: View, or t-sql, or a pass-though query don't matter. if this is indeed a T-SQL function (they are called scaler functions), then this should work. You are free to use T-SQL custom functions you define in that database in any expression such as views or store procs.  As I noted, the ONLY restriction I am aware of is that you MUST prefix the custom T-SQL function with  the schema (dbo.) when used as a expression in any SQL you write.

Comment: See my edit to my post - it should resolve your issue